# Can't access and modify a text file properly Java

Tags: java, java-io

I have a problem accessing a text file in Java.

I created a simple example to demonstrate my problem. I have a simple frame with a single `JButton` and a `JComboBox`. The idea is to update the list displayed in combo box each time the button is pressed.

The process is as follows:

Create a `JComboBox` with default values(empty string array). Update the Combo box with details from a file called `history.txt`; for every button click, change the details of the text file and update combo box again.

Here is the code:

```
package xx;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Xx extends JFrame{


private String filePath = "C:\\Users\\gilbert\\Documents\\11111.xls";
private JButton buttonOpen;
private JComboBox comboBox;
public Xx(){

    String disp[] = {"",""};
    comboBox = new JComboBox(disp);
    comboBox.setEditable(false);
    comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("                                                   ");
    try {
        updateComboBox(getFileHistory());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Xx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    boolean isempty  =false;
    BufferedReader BR = null;
    buttonOpen = new JButton("Open File");
    buttonOpen.setEnabled(true);
    buttonOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

           try {
               BufferedReader bO = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\PinPrinter\\history.txt")));
               int count = comboBox.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
               for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                   String readLine = bO.readLine();
               }
               filePath = bO.readLine();

               bO.close();
               updateFileHistory();
               updateComboBox(getFileHistory());
           } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Xx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Xx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }


       } 
    });
    add(buttonOpen, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
private  String[] getFileHistory() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    int count;
    String tempList[] = null;
    File dir = new File("C:\\PinPrinter");
    if(!dir.isDirectory()){
        boolean made;
        made = dir.mkdir();
    }


    File fileH = new File("C:\\PinPrinter\\history.txt");
    boolean check;
    check = fileH.createNewFile();
    if(check){
        BufferedWriter  gfhw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileH));
        gfhw.write("0");
        gfhw.newLine();
        tempList = new String[1];
        tempList[0] = "0";
        gfhw.close();
    }
    else{

        BufferedReader gfhr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileH));
        count = Integer.parseInt(gfhr.readLine().substring(0, 1));
        tempList = new String[count + 1];
        tempList[0] = String.valueOf(count);
        for(int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++){
            tempList[i] = gfhr.readLine();
        }
        gfhr.close();
    }
    return tempList;
}



private void updateFileHistory() {

    String tempList[] = null;

    BufferedReader ufhR;
    BufferedWriter ufhW;
    CompleteTerminate:
    while(true){
        try {
            ufhR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\PinPrinter\\history.txt")));
            int count = Integer.parseInt(ufhR.readLine());
            if(count < 10){
                count++;    
            }
            tempList = new String[count + 1];
            tempList[0] = String.valueOf(count);
            tempList[1] = filePath;
            for(int i = 2; i < count; i++){
                tempList[i] = ufhR.readLine();
                if(tempList[2].equals(tempList[1])){
                    break CompleteTerminate;
                }
            }
            ufhR.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Xx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Xx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        try {
                ufhW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\PinPrinter\\history.txt")));
                for(String item:tempList){
                    ufhW.write(item);
                    ufhW.newLine();
                }
                ufhW.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Xx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        }
}

private void updateComboBox(String[] tempList){
    comboBox.removeAllItems();
    int count = Integer.parseInt(tempList[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++){
        comboBox.addItem(String.valueOf(i)+ ": "+ tempList[i].subSequence(tempList[i].lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, tempList[i].lastIndexOf("s") + 1));
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Xx cool = new Xx();
    cool.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    cool.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

On the first run the program will create a `history.txt` file. The program gives an error when the `updateFileHistory()` method tries to execute.

Before you try to re-run delete the `C:\PinPrinter` folder or the program will fail from the start because the `getFileHistory()` either requires the `history.txt` file not to exist or not be empty.

Comment: Which error?  On what line?

Comment: The method "updateFileHistory()" that is called when clicking the button. Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. Its like the file doesn't exist somehow.

Comment: And on which line?  NPE usually means you haven't initialised something.  I would look at the error message and the line involved and check everything used cannot be `null`.

Comment: Since some of your tempList elements are `null` I would bet when you write() these is were you are getting an NPE.  I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to see this for yourself.

Comment: I checked. It just doesn't work. I made sure to close all the readers after I was done with them. Its just behaving as if the file doesn't exist. But when the "updateFileHistory()" runs it wipes the file's contents. Please is there anyway u could try running this on ur system? It looks a bit weird and long because i ripped it from the main application. I just don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Instead of assuming you know what the problem is, can you just **read the error message and look at the line** which triggered the error?

Comment: Sorry that I'm being slow. It occurs in line "ufhW.write(item);" in method "updateFileHistory()".

Comment: I should be a psycic ;)  I guessed because item is `null` for some elements of your array.  If you looked at your code in a debugger you would be able to see the value is `null` and why it is `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I made some changes to my code (made templist a field variable) to look at what happens. I don't know how to debug a GUI well (like using breakpoints). It seems that the reading part of the "updateFileHistory()" method gets skipped somehow. Thank you for your help so far. I will try to find a solution :)

Comment: In your IDE, add a breakpoint to a line by clicking on the left hand side of the line and press the debug button.

Comment: That kind of didn't work. Broken Breakpoint. Still thank you for your help. I feel bad making you explain simple things to me.

Comment: I suggest you use `List<String>` instead of a `String[]` as this will not have `null` values if you don't set a value.  I also strongly suggest you learn to use your debugger unless you are sure you will never have another bug ever.